# How to solve AJAX search in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to make *AJAX* searching into my app, but I have a problem.

Please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong, I'm new to *AJAX*.

My Route:

```
Route::get('/retours/{id}/searchpart/{searchquery}', 'RetoursController@searchpart');
```

My Table and Search form, the vars are commented out, else I would always get an error and can't test.

```
{!! Form::open(['class' => 'form-horinzontal']) !!}
    {!! Form::text('search', null, array('required','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Zoeken in onderdelen','onkeyup' => 'search_data(this.value, "result")')) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('zoek', array('class'=>'btn btn-info form-control')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
<br>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Artikelcode</th>
        <th>Artikelcode verkoop</th>
        <th>Omschrijving</th>
        <th>Prijs</th>
        <th>Actie</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if(isset($resultquery))
        @foreach($resultquery as $result)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ url('/parts', $result->id) }}">
                        {{ $result->artikelcode }}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{--{{ $result->artikelcodeverkoop }}--}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{--{{ substr($result->omschrijving,0,50) }}--}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{--€ {{ $result->prijs }}--}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{--<a href="{{ url('/retours/' .$retour->id . '/addpart/'. $result->id) }}" style="margin-right: 10px;" class="pull-right">--}}
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    Aan bon toevoegen
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @else

    @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

And my Controller of course:

```
public function searchpart(Request $request, $searchquery){

    $data = Parts::where('omschrijving','LIKE', '%' .$searchquery.'%')->get();

    return view('retour.updatefill')->with('resultquery',$data);
```

[image]

ajax ofcourse:

```
function search_data(search_value) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'searchpart/' + search_value,
            method: 'GET'
        }).done(function(response){
            $('#myTable').html(response);          
        });
    }
```

- Sometimes I get 500 internet server error
- Sometimes I get 404 not found

I have the feeling I'm doing it terribly wrong.

errors requested by madalin:
[image]

Comment: where is your `ajax`?

Comment: sorry i added @ParthTrivedi

Comment: Please `console(search_value)` are you getting it all the time?

Comment: Use `'/retours/[id]/searchpart/' + search-value` as your `url` in the `$.ajax`.

Comment: this doesnt work @Duvdevan, i think it gets the right URL as seen in the uploaded image..  thx for the comment tho..

Comment: why not use a get variable like normal people and not a custom route?

Comment: What is the Laravel error that is shown under the "Voorbeeld" (= Example) tab in your browser console?

Comment: @piscator Internal server error

Comment: @madalinivascu what do you mean??

Comment: @JordyGroote see my answer below man

Answer (score 0):

Use a get variable not a custom route

```
Route::get('/retours/{id}/searchpart', 'RetoursController@searchpart');

public function searchpart(Request $request){
    $searchquery = $request->get('searchquery');
    $data = Parts::where('omschrijving','LIKE', '%' .$searchquery.'%')->get();

    return view('retour.updatefill')->with('resultquery',$data);
```

ajax:

```
function search_data(search_value) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{action("RetoursController@searchpart")}}' ,
            data:{searchquery:search_value}
            method: 'GET'
        }).done(function(response){
            $('#myTable').html(response);          
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hello thanks for this, the {{action}} needs parameters what shoud i give it ?

Comment: pass the id of the route `{id}` like `action('UserController@profile', ['id' => 1]);`

Comment: I still get internal server error... has this something to do with csrf token?

Comment: and i don't even need the ID so i deleted that from the route

Comment: you need to return something if there is no data returned

Comment: $data = Parts::where('id','LIKE', '%' .$searchquery.'%')->get();
        if($data > 0) {

        } else {
            return "Nothing found";
        }

Comment: what do you mean by `if($data > 0)` are you returning a number ??

Comment: why not use count()?

Comment: that's indeed what i ment, i still get internal server errror tho.  this is killing me

Comment: what errors are in the ajaxed page can you paste them here?

Comment: will add to original post

Comment: the ajax gives no errors whatsoever, this is all i get. the internal server 500

Comment: added in post above ^^

Comment: i mean the error in the body of the xhr request not the response error

Comment: added the new picture

Comment: @JordyGroote  ok this is not woking with the picture and stuf so i want you to open the following url into your project and paste me the screenshot  from that  `/retours/searchpart?searchquery=test` is the url you are trying to ajax to

Comment: it return this,   Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/resources/views/retour/show.blade.php)

Comment: damn hard, your view has a variable that is not returned by your database query

Comment: Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: yes you go to the template and you check every variable if exists

Answer (score 0):

You should be return `json response` to ajax callback.

Try this:

```
public function searchpart(Request $request, $searchquery){

    $data = Parts::where('omschrijving','LIKE', '%' .$searchquery.'%')->get();

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $data
    ], 200); 
}
```

Ajax

```
.done(function(response){
    //do something
    console.log(response.data);       
});
```

Comment: why append a html json to the page?